# SQL Server Table Partitioning different query plan for same TSQL with different parameter

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, database-administration

We are using SQL Server 2012 Table Partitioning. every partition contains almost 5 million of rows and approx size is 600 GB. Database is a part of Availability groups and we are running below query on readable secondary.

Partition column : ConnectionTime - DATETIME - 1 day partition

Total Partition : 1065

Partition Number for 1-Oct-2015 00:00:00.000 --> 1003

Partition Number for 19-Oct-2015 00:00:00.000 --> 1021

```
SELECT COUNT(*),substring(convert(VARCHAR, ConnectionTime, 1), 1, 50) AS [Date]
FROM ReportDB.dbo.TblReport WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ConnectionTime BETWEEN '1-Oct-2015 00:00:00.000'
        AND '1-Oct-2015 23:59:59.997'
GROUP BY substring(convert(VARCHAR, ConnectionTime, 1), 1, 50)

SELECT COUNT(*),substring(convert(VARCHAR, ConnectionTime, 1), 1, 50) AS [Date]
FROM ReportDB.dbo.TblReport WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ConnectionTime BETWEEN '19-Oct-2015 00:00:00.000'
        AND '19-Oct-2015 23:59:59.997'
GROUP BY substring(convert(VARCHAR, ConnectionTime, 1), 1, 50)
```

On this table we have one Clustered Index and one non-clustered index.

From 19-Oct-2015, We are facing issue that same query for 1-oct is seeking cluster index with parallel execution. When any query greater than 19-oct is seeking non-cluster index and not executing parallel.

It generates too much IO for tempdb when ConnectionTime  is greater than 19-oct.

Anyone faces same issue? any solution ?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity.  It looks like you have one partition for every single day.  And it looks like you are trying to select the entire partition.  What happens when you select by partition?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188071.aspx

Comment: @Brad : I can select data by partition id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistics for cluster index was not updated since last 10 days. As it was updated automatically. some how it wasn't updated. Query plan was preparing based on statistics so it won't use cluster index as well partitioning.

Rebuild index works and query are working fine now.